# Old project now shows up blank (no more layers)

Tags: qgis, layers, qgs

I've been working on this project for months now. Today I opened it up and it was blank, no layers, no nothing. I'm using version 3.16 of QGIS

I've tried opening multiple other projects and they all show up blank.
Here's how it looks :
[image]

Comment: Well, did you change anything in your file structure since you opened the projects the last time? Did you receive any error messages when opening them? Did you open the unzipped project using a text editor and check its contents? Does anyone else have access to the projects?

Comment: Random filesystem corruption is a thing for which we all have to prepare. Do you have a backup from which you can restore?